# Get the coefficients of multi-dimensional data

Tags: python, math, matrix, scikit-learn, regression

I have performed a ridge Regression with sklearn for the following data

```
x_1 = np.array([
  [1,0,1],
  [0,1,1],
  [-2,4,0]])
y = np.array([0,0,2])
lr = Ridge(alpha=0.001) 
lr.fit(x_1, y)
coeff = pd.DataFrame(data={'coeff': lr.coef_})
coeff
```

This works very well and I get the required coefficients.

But now I want to use n-dimensional data to get more precise results, something like:

```
x = np.array([
[[1,2],[0,-2],[1,0]],
[[0,-2],[1,4],[1,3]],
[[-2,1],[4,0],[0,-2]]
])
```

But ridge regression doesn't work with high-dimensional Data. What possible ways are there to achieve the desired output?

For me it's important to determine how strongly a vector (or matrix) correlates to the output.

Comment: Why is your second x a 3x3x2 array and not a 3x6 array?

Comment: Because this is how my data looks like? I don't really understand your question. I have additional data that are different from the first part of the tuple.

I have a vector for the first row [1, 0, 1] and now i have additional informations [[1,2],[0,-2],[1,0]] because the second part the 2,-2 and 0 are new informations

Comment: If your new information is new features you should append it horizontally to your existing data and form a 3 rows by 6 columns array. If the new information is new data for the existing three features you should append  it at the bottom of your existing data and form a 6 rows by 3 columns array.

Comment: And as goal variable i would still use y but i double it like [0,0,2,0,0,2] ?

Comment: Yes, if the new data are new data points and their respective labels are 0, 0, 2. I hope the difference between new features and new data points is clear.